# Form is empty when submitted using Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, thymeleaf

I want to fill a list of applications for a university in the frontend. Each entry is supposed to hold two buttons: one for accepting the application and one for rejecting it. I created one form for each submit-button each.

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                            <th scope="col">Firstname</th>
                            <th scope="col">Lastname</th>
                            <th scope="col">Grade</th>
                            <th scope="col">NC</th>
                            <th scope="col">Course</th>
                            <th scope="col">Certificate</th>
                            <th scope="col">Recommendation</th>
                            <th scope="col">Decision</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr th:each="applicationOpen, rowStat: ${lstOpApplications}">
                            <th th:text="${rowStat.count}">1</th>
                            <td th:text="${applicationOpen.firstname}">firstname</td>
                            <td th:text="${applicationOpen.lastname}">lastname</td>
                            <td th:text="${applicationOpen.highschool_grade}">grade</td>
                            <td th:text="${applicationOpen.nc}">nc</td>
                            <td th:text="${applicationOpen.name}">coursename</td>
                            <td th:text="${applicationOpen.highschool_certificate}">certificate</td>
                            <td th:text="${applicationOpen.document}">recommendation</td>
                         

                            <td>
                                <form action="#" th:action="@{/Bewerberubersicht}" th:object="${decisionForm}" method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="application_id" th:field="*{application_id}" value=${applicationOpen.id}"/>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="decision" th:field="*{decision}" value=1/>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i>Accept</button>
                                </form>
                                <form action="#" th:action="@{/Bewerberubersicht}" th:object="${decisionForm}" method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="application_id" th:field="*{application_id}" value=${applicationOpen.id}/>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="decision" th:field="*{decision}" value=2/>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i>Reject</button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I look in the Browser's Dev-Tools I can see that the content of the POST-request is

```
application_id: ""
decision: ""
```

When I replace value=${applicationOpen.id} with e.g. value=5 it is still empty. Hence, it should not be a problem with applicantOpen. Also, the list in the frontend is being filled just fine, so all of that should work. I first thought is is a problem with the DecisionForm class, but it seems my subsequent problems are caused by the issue described here.

Comment: Did you try with adding the quotes? So `value="2"` instead of `value=2` for example?

Answer (score 0):

The `th:field` attribute overrides content of `name` and `value` attributes. The `decisionForm` object seems to have empty fields so all forms have empty values.

Basically using `th:object` with `th:field` is convenient when you need to have your form prepopulated with values. It establishes **initial** state of your form, **not the target**. Using them makes sense for single form, not for multiple forms in loop with varying values.

In your case: please remove both `th:object` and `th:field` attributes. Instead use `value="1"` or `value="2"` for `decision` input, and `th:value="${applicationOpen.id}"` for `application_id` input.